# ASINetworkQueue some image download fails

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am downloading a bunch of images via `ASINetworkQueue`. I have no problems in the simulator, but on the iPad some of the images (each time they are different) are not downloaded. How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

Queue Creation:

```
if (addedPaintings > 0) {
            [currentPaintingsArray addObjectsFromArray:objectsToAdd];
            [unseenPaintings addObjectsFromArray:objectsToAdd];
            [self downloadImages];
        }
        // update plist file if data was altered.
        if (addedPaintings > 0 || removedPaintings > 0)
            [currentPaintingsArray writeToFile:dataFilePath atomically:YES];
        else
            [self completeSync:request.responseStatusCode];
}
```

Image Download method:

```
- (void) downloadImages {
    [networkQueue reset];
    [networkQueue setDelegate:self];
    [networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
    [networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:self.progressView.customView];
    [networkQueue setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageQueueDownloadComplete:)];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in [Globals sharedGlobals].unseenPaintings) {       
        NSString *link = [dict objectForKey:@"link"];
        NSString *smallLink = [dict objectForKey:@"smallLink"];
        if ([link length] != 0) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[URL stringByAppendingString:GALLERY] stringByAppendingString: link]];
            ASIHTTPRequest *downloadRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
            [downloadRequest setDownloadDestinationPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:link]];
            [downloadRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(imageDownloadFailed:)];
            [downloadRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageDownloadComplete:)];
            [downloadRequest setUserInfo:dict];
            [downloadRequest setDelegate:self];
            [networkQueue addOperation:downloadRequest];
            [downloadRequest release];

            NSURL *urlCarousel = [NSURL URLWithString:[[URL stringByAppendingString:WS_IMAGES] stringByAppendingString: smallLink]];
            downloadRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:urlCarousel];
            [downloadRequest setDownloadDestinationPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:smallLink]];
            [downloadRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(imageDownloadFailed:)];
            [downloadRequest setUserInfo:dict];
            [downloadRequest setDelegate:self];
            [networkQueue addOperation:downloadRequest];
            [downloadRequest release];
        }
    }
    [networkQueue go];
}
```

Comment: and what error are you getting, what have you already done to investigate this, etc?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I just don't see some of the images. My guess is that this ASINetworkQueue sometimes overwrites one image file with another.

Comment: And we can only guess, as you don't show us the code.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the code now. Also, if I change the download method from networkQueue to [downloadRequest startAsynchronous], everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments you've left to the question, (Specifically: `Also, if I change the download method from networkQueue to [downloadRequest startAsynchronous], everything works.`) it may be that your request is timing out when being run synchronously.

Another thing you should know is that the "ASI network classes" are no longer being maintained. The developer offers several alternatives [in his blog post announcing the end-of-life of that software](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;).